# CSS active not working

Tags: css

I am using asp.net4.0 and trying to create a menu bar through the use of CSS, 
When i am running the program  the hove and the click work but the active code doesnt any idea why this is happening

**CSS Code**

```
    #main-nav{
        height:29px;
        float:left;
        background-image:url(images/nav-bg.gif);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        background-position:top left;
        width:100%;
    }

    #main-nav ul,
    #main-nav li{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    #main-nav ul{
        height:29px;
        line-height:29px;
        background-image:url(images/nav-bar.gif);
        background-position:right;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        float:left;
        padding:0px 1px 0px 0px;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    }

    #main-nav li{
        height:29px;
        line-height:29px;
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:80px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #main-nav li a{
        height:29px;
        width:80px;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        background-image:url(images/nav-bar.gif);
        background-position:left;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }



    #main-nav li a:link,
    #main-nav li a:visited{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #main-nav li active{
        background-image:url(images/active.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:left;
    }
    #main-nav li a:hover{
        background-image:url(images/active.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:left;
    }
```

**Updated CSS file**

```
#main-nav{
    height:29px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/nav-bg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top left;
    width:100%;
}

#main-nav ul,
#main-nav li{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#main-nav ul{
    height:29px;
    line-height:29px;
    background-image:url(images/nav-bar.gif);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    padding:0px 1px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#main-nav li{
    height:29px;
    line-height:29px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main-nav li a{
    height:29px;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/nav-bar.gif);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}



#main-nav li a:link,
#main-nav li a:visited{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#main-nav li a:active ,#main-nav li a:focus 
{
    color:Aqua;
    background-image:url(images/active.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;

}
#main-nav li a:hover{
    background-image:url(images/active.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
}
```

Comment: The selector doesn't look right, try "#main-nav li a:active"

Comment: I have done that before i asked the question and it still didnt work

Answer (score 2):

There is no `active` tag. Change it to:

```
#main-nav li a:active{
    background-image:url(images/active.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a fiddle and a screenshot? Does the hover work? If not do this, change the selector to: `#main-nav li a:active, #main-nav li a:focus`. Now see if it works.

Comment: Would i Need to call the Class Active In the HTML file

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Weird. Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and see if it works?

Comment: i have and it still dont wokr

Comment: could it be because the link is on my master page